# How to make a redirect in the browser using pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I want to ask the user a question and if they click the *yes* button, then they should be redirected to another page.

Adobe Acrobat allows us to insert JS in the pdf:

```
if (app.alert("Do you want to go on page X?", 2, 3) === 4) {
    // Make the direct somehow.
}
```

I don't think we can use the `location` object there.

Comment: AcroJS help file says: Go to the first page of the document.
this.pageNum = 0;
Advance the document to the next page.
this.pageNum++;

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
if (app.alert("Do you want to go on page X?", 2, 3) === 4) {
    app.launchURL("http://example.com", true);
}
```

The `true` opens in a new browser window, the default is `false` which will load it in Reader.

Comment: Thanks! I have just tried this in the browser but looks like it's not working. Any other ideas?